# Umbraco V9 - Login Error When Cloning From Umbraco Cloud

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, umbraco, umbraco8

I have cloned a new Umbraco cloud instance which I just set up, two days ago. It was cloned via Git to my local repo the database has been created locally as well. But when I try and login, to the local Umbraco backoffice, I get 'Login failed for user'. In the logs I can also see 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character'.

I am using Umbraco Version 9, which is .Net Core.

Tried creating a new admin password but get the same issue. Any idea what I need to add to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use the initial id that was set up when you created the Umbraco Cloud site. Just click on the 'Sign in with Umbraco ID' button and then use that initial login.You will then be in the back office working locally.

[image]